# ionic iOs Push notification permission ask later

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification

Currently when i launch my app the first time on ios the app ask immediately for the push permission.

But i want to delay this permission in order for my users to go through all the signup workflow.

Is it possible to delay the activation for push permission with ionic?

Thanks!

Comment: you ever get this working?  I am trying to do the exact same thing